# How to get the Column Browser in iTunes 11 on the left side?

Tags: itunes

In iTunes 10, I had the Column Browser (the list of Artists/Albums) going down the left side of the main iTunes window.  With the install of iTunes 11, it is back to the top.

I tried going View>Column Browser>.... and the option is not there, and its not in the preferences either. Anyone see a way to get it back on the left side?

Comment: You used to be able to toggle the column browser between the left and top...I cannot find the option now to move it back to the left, it's always on the top. VERY disappointed. Having the column browser on the left allowed you to see far, far more artists and albums at once in the list. Has anyone found the option?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be possible yet in iTunes 11.  You can [downgrade](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20441475#20441475) to 10.7 at your own risk.

Comment: @nondescript1 For now, I think you are right. I have submitted the request on Apple's [feedback page](http://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html) to bring this back, I encourage anyone else that wants this feature back to do the same.

Comment: Horrible update. Horrible. More flatness and more loss of usability / functionality.  These companies will never learn.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bring back the left-side column browser. It is not possible in iTunes 11. The closest approximation I have found is to go to "Artists" view and enable the Sidebar (under the View menu). You can also downgrade to iTunes 10, depending on your system but that can present its own problems.

Answer (score -1):

Under 11.0.2 when library is selected choose view and select column browser then choose show column browser.
.

Comment: This has the same problem as the other answer, this doesn't show the columns on the left side of the actual library.

Comment: It does under artist, genre and playlists.

Answer (score -2):

If you switch to the Songs menu at the top and hit <kbd>command-b</kbd> you will bring up the column browser. If you want the old look, turn the sidebar on again as well.

Comment: I believe OP was asking how to get the column browser to be "docked" to the left as was possible in iTunes 10.x.

Comment: That's the side bar I believe.

Comment: The sidebar would be separate. There was an option in 10.x to have the column browser display either on top of the list or to the left of it. http://grab.by/hTGw

Comment: Indeed, I have also been searching for this without luck.

Comment: @lukiffer is correct, I am looking for the Column Browser to display on the left side of the window.